Typescript string and object intersection type
I have a type that is defined as:
type XX = string & { s: number };

From my understanding this is equivalent to never type.
Why is it not displayed in IntelliJ or VSCode as never, but rather displayed as-is?
const x: XX = { s: 23 }; // Type { s: number; } is not assignable to type string
const y: XX = 's'; // Type string is not assignable to type { s: number; }

It caused a bug in my codebase.
TS-Playground

It's not never because it's intended to support branded primitive types; see linked q/a for more information.
